# Ionic Cordova Build / Manifest Supported Devices on Play Store

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Cordova for building an Android app. I've built and deployed the app to Play Store using Ionic's deployment instructions. This has worked fine apart from, I only support 5674 devices. Many devices like Nexus 5 (which I developed with) is not supported.

I am assuming this is something to do with my config.xml or AndroidManifest so posted below:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="xxx" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>xxx</name>
  <description>
        xxx.
    </description>
  <author email="xxx" href="xxx">
      xxx
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="xxx"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="0.0.3" package="xxx" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find if you remove the `<compatible-screens>` block from your AndroidManifest.xml that will fix it.

Did you add them yourself or was it a plugin?

The reason being is that the Nexus 5 is a xxhdpi screen and the compatible screens doesn't have that. Either add them all (xxxhdpi too) or remove the whole block

Comment: You're right. I had added it in earlier to try and fix a different issue. Looks to be fixed now, thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Only 197 devices supported... But I don't even have the <compatible-screens> tag at all. Is there anything else I should look for? And in my Manifest i have this:  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />